# SQL Server Notifications

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I'm building an application which extracts data from SQL Server, the version of the server might differ from 2005 to 2012 but most important are 2008 and 2012.

If I want to listen to changes to certain tables and rows in the database, and send or fetch these changes and use them in my C# application what is the best approach?

I will not need to update any data in the database, that is the job for another already existing application.

I just want to listen to changes, or poll for changes, or anything like that.

In your experience, what is best, Service Broker? Query notifications? MSMQ? SqlDependency? Change data tracking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "best"? This sounds like a poll question unless you give more specifics about which of these technologies you've tried, what challenges you expect, and how you intend to measure...

Comment: With best i actually mean simplest architecture, I don't need to have the updates instantly, but at least within a minute or two, I'm currently doing my master thesis and this is probably the last thing I'm implementing in my system, and I'm just curious of what people has used before and what they found easy and useful.

Comment: How are records getting INTO the database?

Comment: Via another application, written in c++, and that application gets it's data from a web farm. But the problem is that we can't listen to changes there, because we cannot be sure if they go through.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [SQL Server CLR integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in combination with triggers.

For example you can protocol the changes you wish (let say in a table you create for this purpose), and you can run a watch dog process which pulls the data in constant intervals or at certain points of time up to your needs.

Comment: Have you used it for anything that reminds you of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use SQL Server exposed performance counters.